# Using input to define iterations

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I would like to define the number of iterations `lapply` should go interactively in R-shiny.
So far, putting this number in works, and an output is generated likewise.
 Rendering these outputs is also okay, however the number of iterations is not.

The code at the moment looks like this:

```
ui<-fluidPage(
    numericInput(inputId = "maxk", label = "number of k's", value=5),
    actionButton(inputId="start",label="Start"),
    maxk<-5,

#Instead of this (maxk<-5), I would like write something to get maxk from the output

    lapply(1:maxk,function(k){
                        list(
                        uiOutput(paste("test_",k))
                        )
                            })
                )
```

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

    observeEvent(input$start,{
        maxk<-input$maxk

#And here something should be apply to get maxk into the correct way into the output I assume

        lapply(1:maxk,function(k){
        output[[paste("test_",k)]]<-renderText(k)   
        })
    })

    }
```

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have tried `RenderText()`, but get an error if I attempt to use that as an input for the `lapply()`.

What other possibilities are there go get a numeric output within the server-part that can be used in the ui-part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should give you what you want. Ultimately, the shorter you can make your Shiny code, the better! (That said, I'm sure that someone can find an even shorter way, but this works.)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "maxk", 
    label = "number of k's", 
    value = 5
    ),
  verbatimTextOutput("k_output")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  calc <- reactive({
    lapply(
      1:input$maxk,
      function(k){
        paste0("test_", k)
        }
      )
    })

    output$k_output <- renderPrint(calc())

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope this helps you.